# map is not working on three.js object

Tags: javascript, three.js

```
function create_geometry_0(scene)
{
      var mesh;
      var material;
      var texture;
      var geometry;
         geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
         geometry.attributes = {
         position: {
            itemSize: 3,
            array: new Float32Array([..my object..])
         },
         normal: {
            itemSize: 3,
            array: new Float32Array([..my object..])
         }
         };

         texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('ull.jpg');
         texture.needsUpdate = true;

         material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
            color: 0xFF0000,
            ...other material stuff
//          map: texture
            });
         mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
         scene.add(mesh);

}
```

here everything works unless I add the map into my material. But if I add the map everything just stop working. I don't know why. Should i add anything else to my texture!?

Comment: 1. What does "stops working" mean? 2. Try removing `texture.needsUpdate = true`.

Comment: Didn't work. Stop working simply means my object disappears whenever I try to add the map to material. I have two objects there (a box and a text) and a mouse rotation control system which is working good unless I add the map to my material. But when I do so the box (the object that i try to add my texture on it) disappear and mouse control stop working.

Comment: You should post that as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it worked finally. i think i had two problems. first my object didn't have any texture coordinate. Second maybe i'd better to use a meshbasicmaterial rather than a meshphongmaterial. and by the way there is no need to that texture.needUpdate command. now my material code is this: material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ side: THREE.FrontSide, map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('index_ABASI.jpg') });